# URL logic: unique short description and id

Tags: url, routes

What is the logic behind a URL like this one:

https://foursquare.com/v/the-deli/4f3258b9e4b09c2f1061fc5b

v is probably an abbreviation for "venue".
But is there a specific technical reason to add both short description and id after that?

Comment: Might depend on what this is a URL *to*, no?

Comment: @ScottHunter It is the url to a venue profile. Is there a reason why not to use either the unique description, or the unique id? Is there a reason why to use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "description" is just to make it more readable; it can be left out.